# Is there a way to filter out property-only changes in the TortoiseSVN log?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

The mergeinfo feature of SVN is really useful, but it puts a log entry in the revision log when all that's been changed on a file are svn properties, which we typically don't want to see.

Is there a way to filter out property-only changes in the TortoiseSVN log?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Pull up the log
2. Select the two revisions you want to compare
3. Right-click and select “Compare revisions”

Anything with an entry of “Normal” in the “Action” column had property-only changes.  You can sort on this column and disregard all of those items.  You can’t prevent them from showing up though.