# Filter files in the TortoiseSVN Revision Log Dialog?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is it possible to filter the displayed changed files list for a selected revision? In the repository are stored hundreds of generated files that are commited from time to time. Now it is hard to find a out what's a real change if you have 500 changed files in the commit.

I know it's more or less a usage issue. But if it would help me a lot to filter the files list. Are there any other tools that can do this if it's not possible with TortoiseSVN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal case would be of course to *not* version files that can be generated automatically ;)
[But if you must](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893913/should-i-store-generated-code-in-source-control), then I don't know of a "filename filter" on Tortoise. 
Except maybe, marking those generated files with a special property, in which case you can [sort the diff output in Tortoise based on the property column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411992/is-there-a-way-to-filter-out-property-only-changes-in-the-tortoisesvn-log).

Note: In a command-line session, a simple "`grep -v generated`" would be enough to filter out any file in a "generated" directory.

Comment: Hopped for a unknown "trick". But well, looks like i have to life with it. I'm going to take a further look at the property colum thing.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try looking at the Revision Log.  You can get to it by selecting "Show Log" from the Tortoise SVN context menu.  It has a way of filtering the commit list by file path using a regular expression.
For example, if you enter

```
.java -.jsp
```

it will filter display commits that have modified .java files but do not have modified .jsp files.  So if you know that your generated files are in a particular directory path or have a specific extension, then you can exclude commits that only have those.
If every commit has generated files, then you could try exporting the modified files to a different directory and look through them to see what was changed.  The export feature maintains the directory hierarchy.